What is about 温泉 that is 渋い?
In more than one manga I've seen one character comment he's going to an 温泉 trip and then some other character commenting it's 渋い or he himself wondering if it's too 渋い.
As far I know, 渋い just mean "bitter" what is the actual nuance that connects it to 温泉?

Can you provide a screenshot of the manga?

There is a whole wikipedia article on 渋い: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibui. This might answer your question. I think it relates to how going to an onsen is a traditionally very Japanese thing to do (and traditional Japanese culture is associated with simple elegance), but as to how it is "too 渋い," a native might have a better idea.

In such contexts, 渋い implies a taste that is often associated with older generations. It's not an inherently negative term, but it indicates something not typically favored by younger generations. It may also suggest nicheness, tranquility or a lack of energy. Examples of hobbies that may be considered 渋い by younger generations include classical music, chess, gardening, and haiku. Similarly, 渋いファッション refers to a fashion style that would suit dandy middle-aged men in their 40s or 50s.
